# How to grab data from another table with this relationship setup?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have four tables

City

```
  id
  city
  state_id
```

State

```
 id
 name
```

City_Vendor

```
 id
 vendor_id
 city_id
```

Vendor

```
 id 
 name
```

Now if I do something like this I get the cities and the state_id but not the state name

```
   Vendor::with('cities')->get();
```

This is what I did to get the states in my view which is not ideal..

```
              <?php foreach($vendor['cities'] as $state): ?>
                  @if($state['state_id'] == $city['state_id'])
                    {{$state['state']['state']}}
                    <?php break; ?>
                  @endif
              <?php endforeach;?>
```

I would like to get states name too not just the state_id. What would would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have correct relationship, it should be rather something like that:

```
@foreach ($vendor->cities as $city)
  {{ $vendor->city->city}}, {{$vendor->city->state->name}}
@endforeach
```

In above code you display for one vendor city with state name

and instead of:

```
Vendor::with('cities')->get();
```

you should rather use:

```
Vendor::with('cities.state')->get();
```